# finding a good term order for grobner basis

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computational-geometry

What are the tricks to pick a "good" monomial order to find a Grobner basis for a given ideal?

By good I mean one in which the final Grobner basis has a simple expression in terms of the coefficients of the original polynomials defining the ideal, and/or in which the computation of the normal form of a polynomial with respect to the final basis is fast.

Also, any reference which addresses the above is welcome!